# How to make a splitViewController behave the same on all devices

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

For reasons I would rather not go into, I have a splitViewController that I want to behave the same way on all screens.

In other words, I do not wish to have a split screen with master-detail on the left-right, but would rather it just show the master or the detail, depending on how the user is using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `UISplitViewController`'s `preferredDisplayMode` property to `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeSideBySide` (the default is `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAutomatic`). The system will *try* to honor your wishes, but you'll probably have to specify a custom `primaryContentWidth` or `preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction` property to force it to do this on a compact device.

Comment: ok, thanks, where do i do this? in the MasterSplitViewController? and just in the viewDidLoad? or somewhere else?   and do I use it's own property? like self.splitViewController.UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeSideBySide

Comment: If you have it in a storyboard, then you give it a storyboard ID (in its Identity inspector) or, more likely, you designate it as your storyboard's initial view controller.

Comment: use the storyboard to set a storyboard ID in the identity inspector of the SplitViewController?  Then access it through the masterSplitViewController ?

Comment: Yep. Select your split view controller in the storyboard, switch to the Identity inspector (the third icon in the right-hand view), and give it an ID. Then, in your code (probably in `UIApplicationDelegate`, if your split view controller is the root view controller of your application), set the property.

Comment: Or you can subclass `UISplitViewController`, set your split view controller's storyboard class type to your new subclass, then override the split view controller's `viewDidLoad()` method to set the property.

Comment: Does this work even if the SplitViewController is not my root controller (it isn't)

Comment: Well, then you'll set the properties wherever and whenever you instantiate the split view controller.